# Access form controls inside ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular

I want to access form controls and disable some controls conditionally. In the following code, the form has no controls:

`Component`

```
export class OfferDialogComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

    freemium = false;
    @ViewChild('editForm') editForm: NgForm;

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        this.editForm.form.get("trialPeriod").disable();
    }
}
```

`Template`

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()" #editForm="ngForm">
```

How can I access and initialize form controls conditionally?

Comment: do you want to access controls after disable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**From Angular Docs**

> Template-driven forms delegate the creation of their form controls to
>   directives. To avoid changed after checked errors, these directives
>   take more than one cycle to build the entire control tree. That means
>   you must wait until the next change detection cycle happens before
>   manipulating any of the controls from within the component class.
>
> For example, if you inject the form control with a `@ViewChild(NgForm)`
>   query and examine it in the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook, you'll
>   discover that it has no children. You must trigger a change detection
>   cycle using `setTimeout()` before you can extract a value from a
>   control, test its validity, or set it to a new value.

Modified Code:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  setTimeOut(() => {
    this.editForm.form.get('trialPeriod').disable();
  });
}
```

Or You could use  `ngAfterViewChecked`

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
class App {
  constructor(private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    if (this.editForm.controls.name) this.editForm.form.get('name').disable();

    this.cdRef.detectChanges(); 
//Forcing change detection to avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
Define form control 
<input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl">
 
In .ts :-
emailFormControl = new FormControl('default value');

and get value using this.emailFormControl.value

see : https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples
```