# Angular's template-driven form reset is not working using component class

Tags: angular, typescript

**Component Template**

```
<form #formGroupContactUs_Template = "ngForm" (ngSubmit)="contactUsTemplateSubmit()">        
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name">
       <!-- {{name!.value}} -->
       <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2" type="submit" 
       [disabled]="this.formGroupContactUs_Template.status != 'VALID'">Submit</button>
       <a class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="clearAll()">Clear All</a>
    </form>
```

**Component Class**

```
export class TemplateComponent implements OnInit {
 
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  model: any = {
    name: "",
  };

  contactUsTemplateSubmit() {
    console.log(this.model); //form Values
  }

  clearAll() {
    this.model.reset(); // not working
  }

}
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6-template-driven-form-validation-hncilc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts,  https://stackblitz.com/edit/using-data-service-kgu7w7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html,app%2Fapp.component.ts,app%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is solution for clearing the form

**in .ts**

```
 clearAll(InputFormValue: ngForm) {
   InputFormValue.form.reset();//this will work
  }
```

**in .html**

```
<form #formGroupContactUs_Template="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="contactUsTemplateSubmit(formGroupContactUs_Template)">        
       <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="model.name">
       <!-- {{name!.value}} -->
       <button class="btn btn-primary mr-2" type="submit" 
       [disabled]="this.formGroupContactUs_Template.status != 'VALID'">Submit</button>
       <a class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="clearAll(formGroupContactUs_Template)">Clear All</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: <a class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="clearAll()">Clear All</a>  clearAll() have an error in templae: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.ngtsc(2554)

Comment: i update the code, need to pass the parms to .ts

Comment: working now with changes

Answer (score 1):

For programmatic approach you could get the form in `ngAfterViewInit()` and call reset on it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52167560/15439733

Or on template this would work too.

```html
   <a class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="formGroupContactUs_Template.reset()">Clear All</a>
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-workbench-template-driven-form-btfxnf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html